# How does strpos() function in PHP return int as well as boolean?

Tags: php, function, strpos

This is what w3School says about the **strpos()** function :

> Returns the position of the first occurrence of a string inside another string, or FALSE if the string is not found.

How is the function defined? Is it possible to write such functions which returns values of 2 different datatypes in other languages as well?

Comment: Did you hear about "If condition"

Comment: Yes, I thought the same since you don't have to specify the return datatype of a function in PHP . But I was just wondering if it is possible to write such functions in C++ or Java?

Comment: that is the reason i like php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many dynamically typed languages allow you to return whatever you want from a function. Strongly typed languages generally don't.

In PHP a function can return *anything* it wants, including booleans, ints, strings, null, arrays, all kinds of objects, whatever you need. It's the same in for example Javascript and Lua, which are also dynamically typed.

Just make sure to check the return type of the function if it can be different kinds of things. Especially with things like int(0) and false, which are considered equivalent if you use an == comparison. Use === to make sure it's the right type.

Comment: This answer helps me a lot. I've been learning Python as well and I never wrote a function that returns values of 2 different datatypes and I wrote functions like I'm writing it in Java, I guess this is what happens if you're coming from a Java background!

Answer (score 1):

Other languages do not have `loosely typed variables and function returns`. Take for example C.

Taken from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php):

```
PHP is a dynamic, loosely typed language, that uses copy-on-write and reference counting.
```